# strtotime returns false for large dates php5.6

Tags: php

In my php5.6 the output of the following code is `false`

```
$test =  strtotime("2050-07-31 00:00:00.000000");
```

when running this code using the online compiler attached below it returns `2542838400`

https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_compiler

What would cause this code to be returning `false` for us and how would we go about fixing this?

Comment: **Danger**: PHP 5.6 is out of date and unsupported (even for security fixes). Upgrade to a supported version of PHP.

Comment: @Quentin yea it was a legacy project i inherited. The migration to php7 is underway. but still having to fix bugs as we go.

Comment: You should be moving to PHP8.1. [PHP7.4 is EOL in November 2022](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php) (6 months from this comment).

Comment: @mark_b one version at a time. haha thats the plan though.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to many other reasons why [`strtotime` returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=strtotime%20returns%20false), there can be another one - you have **32-bit** computing system.

Which means that values that are greater than `2 147 483 647` (and `2 542 838 400` **is**) cannot be stored in a variable.

So, you have to check your architecture and move to **64-bit** computing system.

Comment: see also the [notes](https://www.php.net/strtotime): "The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer.)"